# SQL Filter - filtering with combination of multiple colums

Tags: sql, postgresql

## table1

```
person    | zipcode     | timestamp               | event  | device
--------------------------------------------------|--------|------
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:07:03.001 | chat   | pc
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | email  | phone
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | chat   | phone
amar      | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:09:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:10:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 22222       | 2016-09-28 20:10:03.001 | chat   | phone
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:05:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:05:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 21:07:03.001 | chat   | phone
```

**Output desired -**
records
for all zipcodes for all hours where records with `pc` device is present

## output table for above example

The only qualifying `zipcode, timestamp_hour` combination is `11111, 2016-09-28 20`

```
person    | zipcode     | timestamp               | event  | device
--------------------------------------------------|--------|------
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | email  | phone  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:07:03.001 | chat   | pc
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | email  | phone
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | chat   | phone
```

**pseudocode**

1. create temp table of `zipcode, timestamp_hour` combination with filter `device='pc'` to get qualifying `zipcode, timestamp_hour` list
2. apply #1 as a filter with `table1`

For #1 above, the code i've is as below , need help with #2

```
with zipcode_hour as (
  select zipcode,   date_trunc(`hour`, timestamp) as timestamp_hour
      from table1
      where device = 'pc'
      group by zipcode, timestamp_hour
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query

```
SELECT person
    ,zipcode
    ,timestamp1
    ,event
    ,device
FROM table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM table1 b
        WHERE b.device = 'pc'
            AND date_trunc('hour', a.timestamp1) = date_trunc('hour', b.timestamp1)
            AND a.zipcode = b.zipcode
        );
```

Complete result [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/12312/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a self join and where clause

```
select distinct t1.person, t1.zipcode, t1."timestamp", t1.event, t1.device
from table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t2.zipcode = t1.zipcode
               and date_trunc('hour', t2."timestamp") = date_trunc('hour', t1."timestamp")
where t2.device = 'pc'
```

This looks for all entries `t1.*, t2.device` having the same `zipcode` and `hour`, but keeps only the ones where `t2.device` is `pc`. The `distinct` keyword is needed to weed out duplicate entries.